# event listener on scoped session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, event-listener

I am trying to add an event listener to the `before_commit` event of an SQLAlchemy Session inside of a Flask application. When doing the following

```
def before_commit(session):
    for item in session:
        if hasattr(item, 'on_save'):
            item.on_save(session)

event.listen(db.session, 'before_commit', before_commit)
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "app.py", line 60, in <module>
    event.listen(db.session, 'before_commit', before_commit)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\event\api.py", line 49, in listen
    _event_key(target, identifier, fn).listen(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\event\api.py", line 22, in _event_key
    tgt = evt_cls._accept_with(target)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\events.py", line 1142, in _accept_with
    "Session event listen on a scoped_session "
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Session event listen on a scoped_session requires that its creation callable is associated with the Session class.
```

I can't find the correct way to register the event listener. The documentation actually states that `event.listen()` also accepts a `scoped_session`, but it seems like it does not?!

---

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.SessionEvents

> The  listen() function will accept Session objects as well as the return result of
>   sessionmaker() and scoped_session().
>
> Additionally, it accepts the Session class which will apply listeners to all Session
>   instances globally.

Comment: Can you post more code about how you're setting up db.session so we can make sure you're doing that correctly? My guess is that db.session isn't set up properly.

Comment: See https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/182

Comment: @opyate is right. You have encountered well known issue described on that link. However, it looks like it still not fixed yet.

Answer (score 5):

it means that the factory you've passed to scoped_session() must be a sessionmaker():

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import event

# good

ss1 = scoped_session(sessionmaker())

@event.listens_for(ss1, "before_flush")
def evt(*arg, **kw):
    pass

# bad

ss2 = scoped_session(lambda: Session)

@event.listens_for(ss2, "before_flush")
def evt(*arg, **kw):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

To give another example, this codebase won't work:
https://sourceforge.net/p/turbogears1/code/HEAD/tree/branches/1.5/turbogears/database.py

```
# bad

def create_session():
    """Create a session that uses the engine from thread-local metadata.

    The session by default does not begin a transaction, and requires that
    flush() be called explicitly in order to persist results to the database.

    """
    if not metadata.is_bound():
        bind_metadata()
    return sqlalchemy.orm.create_session()

session = sqlalchemy.orm.scoped_session(create_session)
```

Instead it needs to be something like the following:

```
# good

class SessionMakerAndBind(sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker):
    def __call__(self, **kw):
        if not metadata.is_bound():
            bind_metadata()
        return super(SessionMakerAndBind, self).__call__(**kw)

sessionmaker = SessionMakerAndBind(autoflush=False, 
                   autocommit=True, expire_on_commit=False)
session = sqlalchemy.orm.scoped_session(sessionmaker)
```